# Module Homomorphisms and the nature of abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, abelian-groups

There is a fundamental result specifying that all abelian groups are **$\Bbb Z$-modules**.

We are trying to use this fact to find out:

Does there exist an abelian group $H$ which is not isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$ or $\{e\}$,
such that if $G$ is abelian and there is a surjective homomorphism $f : G \to H$, then $G\cong \ker(f) \times H$.

Now my idea:

No, we cannot find such $H$. If $G$ is finite, we can characterize $G$ as $\Bbb Z_{p}$ where $p$ is prime. Now if $G\cong \ker(f) \times H$ then contradicting $p$ being a prime.

If $G$ is infinite, I don't know where to start.

**EDITED**

Thanks for Stefan's answer now my head clears up a bit. Let us wrap the question up. Now, if we can find a section map from $G$ to $\Bbb Z \oplus\Bbb Z$ and we are done. However note that we can define s: $\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z$ $\to$ $G$ with $s(p,q) = a^p b^q$ where $f(a) = (1,0)$ and $f(b) = (0,1)$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: @Shaun will improve my formatting!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not true that every finite abelian group is cyclic. The simplest example of this is the Klein group $C_2\times C_2$.

What you are asking is: for what kind of $H$ is every short exact sequence
$$
0\to A\to G\to H\to 0
$$
split? These kinds of questions are the domain of homological algebra. In that language, your question is: What are the *projective* abelian groups? The answer is that they are precisely the free abelian groups.

So, the group $H=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ works, as do more exotic things like $\mathbb{Z}^\mathbb{R}$, but such examples are all you can get.